# Show placeholder text for unchanged properties in a PropertyGrid

Tags: winforms, propertygrid

I am trying to figure out how to add placeholder string value on every property inside a property grid that was not changed from the user.

So let's say you are trying to edit some object when you get prompted to do so you will get the following form.

[image]

If you changed the color property for example the result would be the following.

[image]

I tried to see if there is an attribute but it seems that there is not. DefaultValue is not suitable because the message is a string and the underlying property could be anything.

The question is if this is possible using combinations of Editors and TypeConverters.

Thanks.

Comment: The PropertyGrid uses strings to represent those Property values, so, it's always a string. You can use a TypeConverter to convert a value that the PropertyGrid should use. Use a static string as the default representation of the DefaultValue of the Property shown in the PropertyGrid (your `"Not changed"` string), so that string converts to a Color in a custom TypeConverter. Your `DefaultValue()` attribute can be `[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "255, 128, 255")]`

Comment: @Jimi I tried to play with that already. Either I am doing something wrong or I don't know what is going on.